# Pigeonhole principle applications

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let ${\{a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_9\}\subset \mathbb{N}}$  with $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^9 a_i = 30.$ Then, show that there exist $ i,j, k\in
\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\},\ i,j,k$ pairwise different, such that $a_i+a_j+a_k \geq 12$. You may use pigeonhole principle

Comment: Please show what you have tried...

Comment: Not getting what to do!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: Assume not:  Without loss of generality, assume that $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_8 \leq a_9.$  Then, $a_7 + a_8 + a_9 \leq 11.$  This means $a_7 \leq 3.$  
So, $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_6 \leq 18,$ and $a_7 + a_8 + a_9 \leq 11.$  Therefore, what can you say about $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_9$?

Comment: In my opinion, re my previous comment, the solution to this problem does not involve the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots$.
If $a_1+a_2+a_3<12 $ then $a_4+\cdots+a_9\ge19$ and so $a_4\ge\lceil 19/6\rceil=4$.
Then $a_1,a_2,a_3\ge4$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3\ge12$, a contradiction.